# D3 - tree nodes not built from external JSON file

Tags: json, d3.js, tree

I'm having difficulty processing external JSON data to build/dispaly a tree. The issue is that nodes are not built from received JSON file. The code only looks as at the JSON data as one object and does not create leafs(other nodes)

When adding the same JSON data as array inside HTML file, the same code creates nodes and displays the tree correctly.

Here is an  extract of the code in question:

```
<body onload="myFunction()">

    <script type="text/javascript" >
        function myFunction()
        {
            d3.json("/data/mydata.json", function (error, data) {
            var root2 = [data];
            root = root2[0];
           ........... other stuff comes here .....
          var nodes = tree.nodes(root.reverse());
```

The browser debugger gives me the following:

```
nodes
```

[Array[1]0: Object 
childern: Array[2]
name: "Max"
parent: "null"
**proto**: Object
depth: 0
length: 1
x: 230
y: 0
**proto**: Array[0]

JOSN file is at the bottom

## I appreciate your feedback in this regard.

```
[{
    "name": "Max",
    "parent": "null",
    "size": 4938,
    "childern": [
        {
            "name": "David",
            "parent": "Max",
            "Childern": [
                {
                    "name": "Craig",
                    "parent": "David",
                    "size": 3938
                },
                {
                    "name": "Robin",
                    "parent": "David",
                    "size": 3812
                },
                {
                    "name": "Anna",
                    "parent": "David",
                    "size": 743
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Peter",
            "parent": "Max",
            "Childern": [
                {
                    "name": "Jeff",
                    "parent": "Peter",
                    "size": 3534
                },
                {
                    "name": "Buffy",
                    "parent": "Peter",
                    "size": 5731
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

}
```

]

Answer (score 0):

Your external JSON file appears to have the 'children' element with a capital 'C' for the lower tiers of data, but with lower case 'c' at the top tier.

Additionally they were misspelled as 'Childern' which may have been causing problems (you will want to check your JavaScript to see how you spelled it there and make it consistent).

I was able to do a quick experiment with an external JSON file and I can confirm that you will get a problem similar to what you describe. So use lower case characters (or at least consistent characters and spelling) for the word 'children' in your data.

Try with the data per below;

```
[{
    "name": "Max",
    "parent": "null",
    "size": 4938,
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "David",
            "parent": "Max",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Craig",
                    "parent": "David",
                    "size": 3938
                },
                {
                    "name": "Robin",
                    "parent": "David",
                    "size": 3812
                },
                {
                    "name": "Anna",
                    "parent": "David",
                    "size": 743
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Peter",
            "parent": "Max",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Jeff",
                    "parent": "Peter",
                    "size": 3534
                },
                {
                    "name": "Buffy",
                    "parent": "Peter",
                    "size": 5731
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

}
```

Comment: corrected JSON file but same result returned. Calling nodes = tree.nodes(root) returned the same input array without decomposing it into nodes

Comment: The ds.js code  line 6464 fails at  if ((childs = children.call(hierarchy, node, node.depth)) && (n = childs.length)) . Instead of getting next child it breaks at this point and returns only one node which starting point only

Comment: Check your JavaScript code for the correct spelling and capitalization as well. Both code and external file must be consistent.

Comment: If possible great a gist for bl.ocks.org or a jsfiddle.